# Referencing another bean without using XML's ref tag

Tags: java, spring

I need to access a bean from another bean in Spring. The obvious solution to this, that I know of, is to use the ref tag in the spring config file. But let's say I am not able to modify the spring config file. Is there another way to access beans within other beans?

Comment: You mean access it programatically?  Can you post some more details about your problem?

Comment: Please look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad

Comment: Yes programmatically or via annotations. But I'm trying to avoid modifying the XML to access the other beans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options:

- use annotations - `@Inject private AnotherBean bean;` (or `@Autowired`) (preferred)
- get ahold of the `ApplicationContext` (for ex. implement `ApplicationContextAware`) and call `.getBean(..)`

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```
class MyBean {
    @Autowired
    private OtherBean theBeanYouWantToGet;
}
```

XML:

```
<beans ...>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <import resource="the-other-xml-file-that-you-can't-touch.xml"/>
    <bean class="...MyBean"/>
</beans>
```