# Reference to singleton bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications, application-singleton

I'm new to Spring and thus apologies in advance if the questions seems to be trivial.

When I declare a bean in spring it is singleton by default. When spring initializes beans from config.xml it's using default creator. If I declare my private creator and getInstance method for a class, I don't get reference to the bean created during Spring initialization - I simply create same class again and this class is referenced when getInstance() is called any time later.

My question is how can I get reference to the singleton created during initialization (to the bean defined in config.xml) from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class implements the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) then there is no way `getInstance()` will return an instance other then what Spring has created.

> how can I get reference to the singleton created during initialization

Basically, you should have it [injected](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html) to the other class, where you will need it.
And you can also refer to it by [`ApplicationContext.getBean()`, although it is not that elegant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that is what I was looking for but have to have a look at link given maksimov below.

Comment: Sure. Just note, that I have given you this same link (the last one).

Comment: @maksimov, I have checked and figured that [you had posted your answer several minutes before I posted mine](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71138/who-answered-first?MyUserId=176569&OtherUserId=211197). However, believe me, I had not seen your answer before I posted mine. We just independently concluded, that this is a relevant link -- which is a good thing.

Comment: @bpgergo there was a smiley in my comment after all. it's all for the common good so don't worry (i don't).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a factory method in your code, then make xml configuration call that factory method instead of a constructor. DO NOT call `getInstance` from your Java code.

```
<bean id="fromFactory" class="org.example.MyFactory" factory-method="getInstance" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring will create a single instance of your class by default.  It will call the class's constructor once.  I think you have confused this with the

```
public static void getInstance()
```

idiom for singletons in Java which is an attempt to enforce in your class that you can never have more than one instance.

Spring has constructed a single instance of your class and is storing it in the Spring container ready for you to use.  To get a reference to the instance Spring has created, you need to retrieve it from Spring's application context.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the confusion :) Definitely will keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be relevant to your question:
[Why is Spring's ApplicationContext.getBean considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad)

There's a number of ways: you can get your bean instance from ApplicationContext, you can @Autowire it, etc.