# Retrieving beans that are scope prototype using getBean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad) that using  is considered applicationContext.getBean("somebeananmehere") is bad.

if that so, how would I programmatically get beans (depends on the user on what kind of bean he wants, let's say he can choose different grocery items eg apple,soap,detergent)?

let's say

```
switch(num){
  case 1 : myGrocery  = (GroceryItem) applicationContext.getBean("SOAP");break;
  case 2: myGrocery = (GroceryItem) applicationContext.getBean("APPLE");break;
  default:
   //more code here
}
```

this is what I am doing in my application where the user is selecting his or her grocery items. (This is a console application)

if applicationContext.getBean is considered bad, then what is the alternative ?

Comment: Like I said in a comment in the question you linked, I fail to see why you should limit how you use Spring just to satisfy a strict interpretation of IoC. Spring is about more than just inversion of control. If using Spring as an object factory through `getBean()` works well in your design, then I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **Lookup Method Injection**.

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
class Example {

  private SOAP soap;

  @Autowired
  public void setSoap(SOAP soap) {
    this.soap= soap;
  }

  private APPLE apple;

  @Autowired
  public void setApple(APPLE apple) {
    this.apple= apple;
  }


  public void yourMethod(int num) {
   switch(num){
    case 1 : myGrocery  = (GroceryItem) soap;break;
    case 2: myGrocery = (GroceryItem) apple;break;
    default:
     //more code here
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: if I call getApple will it return me a new instance ?

Comment: in spring there are diffrent scopes , if it is singleton scope it will create only one insatnce. check this link http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: if the scope of the bean is prototype?

Comment: if you call getter of bean it will gives new object when the scope os 'prototype'

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring's `factory-method` option. Just write your factory method to return the right class and in your xml beans:

```
<bean factory-method="your factory method name" class="your class" />
```

Comment: see spring documentation. look for factory-method section 3.3.2.3 Instantiation using an instance factory method: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html