# How to pass parameters dynamically to Spring beans

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am new to Spring.

This is the code for bean registration:

```
<bean id="user" class="User_Imple"> </bean>
<bean id="userdeff" class="User"> </bean>
```

and this is my bean class:

```
public class User_Imple implements Master_interface {

    private int id;
    private User user; // here user is another class

    public User_Imple() {
        super();
    }

    public User_Imple(int id, User user) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
    }

    // some extra functions here....
}
```

and this is my main method to perform action:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/bean.xml");
    Master_interface master = (Master_interface)context.getBean("user");

    // here is my some operations..
    int id = ...
    User user = ...

    // here is where i want to get a Spring bean
    User_Imple userImpl; //want Spring-managed bean created with above params
}
```

Now I want to call this constructor with parameters, and these parameters are generated dynamically in my main methods. This is what I mean by I want to pass dynamically – not statically, like declared in my `bean.config` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at [Constructor injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators).

Also, Have a look at [IntializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) and [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) for other life cycle interception of a springbean.

Comment: Can you please cite references for why `setter` injection is preferred over constructor

Comment: "The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection as it enables one to implement application components as immutable objects and to ensure that required dependencies are not null...Setter injection should primarily only be used for optional dependencies that can be assigned reasonable default values within the class" - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: I think by "dynamically" the user meant he wanted to pass the arguments in the main method, or generally at the time of getting the bean.  calling getBean(...) and passing arguments directly works, but moving this call to a locator (Service Locator pattern) could be done to avoid the dependency on Spring Framework in your code.  Locator can be passed in as bean instead, and the ApplicationContextAware locator can call getBean(bean, arg1, arg2...). Bean scope should be "prototype".

see also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad

Comment: @Chris how would one remove the hardcoded values from applicationContext.xml inside bean tag as in case of Singelton - Beans get initialised eagerly and please explain with Prototype scope also.

Answer (score 33):

If i get you right, then the correct answer is to use `getBean(String beanName, Object... args)` method, which will pass arguments to the bean. I can show you, how it is done for Java based configuration, but you'll have to find out how it is done for an XML based configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
      
  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")  // As we want to create several beans with different args, right?
  String hello(String name) {
    return "Hello, " + name;
  }
}

// and later in your application

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
String helloCat = (String) context.getBean("hello", "Cat");
String helloDog = (String) context.getBean("hello", "Dog");
```

Is this what are you looking for?

---

### UPDATE

This answer gets too much upvotes and nobody looks at my comment. Even though it's a solution to the problem, it is considered as a Spring *anti-pattern* and you shouldn't use it! There are several different ways to do things right using factory, lookup-method, etc.

Please use the following SO post as a point of reference:

- [How to instantiate Spring managed beans at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809838/how-to-instantiate-spring-managed-beans-at-runtime)

Comment: Please be aware that it is not the best solution when using "DI", because actually here we have kinda "service locator" (which is opposite to DI). Usually, when you met too much context.getBean it means that something is done in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answers proposed above to use constructor injection/setter injection doesn't work perfectly for the use case you are looking for.
Spring more or less takes static argument values for constructors/setters. I don't see a way to dynamically pass values to get a Bean from Spring Container.
However, if you want to get instances of User_Imple dynamically, I would recommend using a factory class User_Imple_Factory

```
 
    public class User_Imple_factory {
        private static ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/bean.xml");

        public User_Imple createUserImple(int id) {
            User user = context.getBean("User");
            return new User_Imple(id, user);
        }
    }
```

Comment: implement ApplicationContextAware to avoid creating a new ApplicationContext that might be created somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor injection can help you. In this case you may need to generate a POJO with ID and user as its attributes and pass POJO to constructor. In constructor injection in config file  you can refer this constructor with pojo as reference. So you will be handle the dynamic value of data in ID and User.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps letting the `User_Imple` be an ordinary Pojo (instead of a Spring bean) will solve your problem?

```
<!-- Only use User as a Spring Bean -->
<bean id="userdeff" class="User"></bean>
```

Java:

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/bean.xml");
    User user = context.getBean(User.class);

    int id = // dynamic id
    Master_interface master = new User_Imple(id, user);
}
```

Comment: ya its good  @matsev, if I have less no. of class we directly use POJOs but  in MVC we completly hide the business file..
then we go through beans..

Comment: Then you need a factory class which you can reference from Spring. Spring uses (more or less) only Singletons