# In Spring-MVC, how do I dynamically set constructor arguments of a session attribute?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, session-state

We are building a webapp that communicates with a remote API. I would like to design the client for this remote API like this:

```
def RemoteApi
  constructor (username, password)
  getCurrentUser()  //implementation will use username and password
  getEmployees()  //implementation will use username and password
  ...
```

The point being, I want to pass in the credentials to this client during construction, and have all the other methods use these credentials. My second requirement is I want this `RemoteApi` instance to be in the session.

I have found out how to pass dynamic constructor arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997034/how-to-pass-parameters-dynamically-to-spring-beans).

I have found out how to create a session attribute [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/).

But I can't figure out a way to combine these two techniques. From what I gather, you have to instantiate a session attribute in its own getter-like method. This getter-like method won't have access to the form's fields so I won't be able to pass in credentials at this point.

Here's where I'm stuck:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("remoteClient")
public class LoginController {

    @Value("${company.name}")
    private String companyName;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteClient remoteClient;

    @ModelAttribute("remoteClient")
    public RemoteClient addRemoteClientToSession() {
        return remoteClient;  //how do initialize this with credentials in here?
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showLogin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("credentials", new Credentials());
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials, Map<String, Object> model) {
        if (remoteClient.auth(companyName, credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword())) {
            model.put("fullname", remoteClient.findCurrentUser().getName());
            return "projectView";
        } else {
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Maybe the solution has to do with [this technique](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-session/). I didn't know about `ModelAndView` before this.

Comment: If you got a working solution for this, please post an answer :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not sure if I do yet.  If it works I'll update

Answer (score 0):

The article I linked to in the question did have the necessary technique in it.  What I would do is create an `@Autowired` `RemoteApiFactory` that has a `newInstance(Credentials)` method and pass that into `addObject`.  The implementation of `newInstance` would probably end up using the `new` keyword.  If anyone knows how to avoid this detail, I'd love to hear it.

Here's its example tweaked for my needs:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("remoteApi")
public class SingleFieldController {

    @Autowired
    private RemoteApiFactory remoteApiFactory;    

    @RequestMapping(value="/single-field")
    public ModelAndView singleFieldPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("single-field-page");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/remember")  
    public ModelAndView rememberThought(@MethodAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("remoteApi", remoteApiFactory.newInstance(credentials));
        modelAndView.setViewName("single-field-page");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```