# Call service method from non controller class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In HomeController i am doing the following

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private EUserService userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map) {
       User user=(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
       EUser currentUser = userDao.findUserByName(user.getUsername());
           System.out.println(currentUser.getUserName());
        }
}
```

It works fine and shows me the output properly. Now If I do the same thing in a non controller type class like following

```
public class Utility {
    @Autowired
    private EUserService userDao;

    public void getLoggedUser() {
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        EUser currentUser = (EUser) userService.findUserByName(user
                .getUsername());
        System.out.println(currentUser.getUserName());

    }
}
```

it gives me the following NullPointerException

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Ebajar] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How to fix this??

Comment: What was the line that threw the `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you are calling this not from controller. The problem is that your are calling this from class that is not managed by Spring, so the `userDao` is not injected here.

It think that "right" solution is to turn your utility to Spring bean, e.g. marking it as `@Service` and call it via Spring. Alternatively you can retrieve it programmatically using `ApplicationContext.getBean()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad) for details)

Answer (score 1):

you should declare/annotate your `Utility` class as a spring bean so that let other bean get injected. in this case, it is `EUserService`

try adding `@Component` to your `Utility` class. I assumed your package is involved by spring annotated bean scanning settings.

Comment: "I assumed your package is involved by spring annotated bean scanning settings." what does this means?

Comment: @LynAs it means, your package should be included in spring's annotated bean scanning config. If you add `@Component` or `@Service`

Answer (score 1):

Only Spring managed bean can autowire an instance. Read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html)

You annotate Utility with @Component.