# Issue getting Bean into a Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, dao

In Spring MVC I've this `models.UserDAO` class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAO implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory _sessionFactory;

  private Session getSession() {
    return _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }

  public void save(User user) {
    getSession().save(user);
    return;
  }

  public User getById(long id) {
    return (User) getSession().load(User.class, id);
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    // implementation 
    // ...
  }

} // class UserDAO
```

And this `controllers.UserController` class:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext _appContext;

  @RequestMapping(value="/users/create")
  @ResponseBody
  public String create(@RequestBody User user) {
    // ...

    UserDAO userDao = _appContext.getBean(UserDAO.class);
    userDao.save(user);

    // ...
  }

} // class UserController
```

So far everything is working: the user is correctly saved in the db through the UserDAO save method.

Now I implemented another controller `controllers.MainController`:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext _appContext;

  @RequestMapping(value="/user")
  public String profile()
    // ...

    UserDAO userDao = _appContext.getBean(UserDAO.class);

    // ...
  }

} // class MainController
```

In this latter controller I've an error getting the Bean: `No qualifying bean of type [myproject.models.UserDAO] is defined`

Could be the error the way I get the bean?:

```
_appContext.getBean(UserDAO.class);
```

---

**EDIT**

I tried to add this in my JavaConfig:

```
@Bean
public UserDAO userDao(){
  return new UserDAO();
}
```

and I replaced the `ApplicationContext _appContext` autowired with the UserDAO injection:

```
@Autowired
private UserDAO userDao;
```

but now I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myproject.models.UserDAO myproject.controllers.MainController.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [myproject.models.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Can you post what your Spring configuration looks like?

Comment: See here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/70649891d5869bfbee11

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you set the UserDAO class in your beans.xml (or equivalent JavaConfig class depends on which you use in your application)?
2. Why don't you inject the UserDAO instance itself into the controller? Seems to me that you're applying a Service Locator (anti)pattern currently.

Comment: You can find more on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad

Comment: Checkout my edit on the first post where I tried your suggestion.

Comment: @andre
I hope the package scan is fine and both controllers lies inside same package

Comment: @ankur-singhal thanks, how can I check if the package scan is fine?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot and JavaConfig (so I don't have the context.xml file)

Comment: You should update your tags to reflect that you are using Spring Boot

Comment: @andre please post the complete code for controllers, showing imports as well.

Comment: also show the code where you have added @ComponentScan

Comment: Here there is the code for my controller: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5bb07da9bd680506daf

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have the `@ComponentScan` in the class myproject.Application: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5cfff2ea24e2f83cd653

Comment: can you try adding packages as below
@ComponentScan({"com.controllers","com.controlles"})
something like.

Comment: Sorry was my mistake, both controllers are in the package "myproject.controllers" (I fixed my post now)... However I tried `@ComponentScan({"com.controllers"})` and `@ComponentScan({"myproject.controllers"})` but they doesn't resolve my error.