# Is there a difference Between using @Lookup, Provider or injecting ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I want to inject prototype beans into a singleton factory.
we're considering 4 options, and would like someone to  emphasize the differences.

Sorted according to my personal preference:

1. use `@lookup` method annotation (we use code based configuration).
2. `@Autowired` a [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) (one for each bean) and `get()` for each type.
3. Provide static access to `ApplicationContext.getBean()` from anywhere in the application, and `getBean()` from there.
4. inject ApplicationContext, and `getBean()`.

I know `getBean()` [is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad), but for some reason, I see many answers directing this way.

(whats the big difference between options 2 & 3 ?)

Comment: 3 is something that could haunt you in a nightmare, but shouldn't make it to reality. 4 is close to that, but lamer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - it does feel wrong & dirty, but I need a real explanation why we have to destroy this piece of code.

Comment: My problem is where to start. Global variables are always bad because you  completely lose control over their scope of usage; exposing the ApplicationContext as a global is particularly disgusting because it's the entrails of your entire application: now any piece of code, anywhere, can do to it what it wants. IoC stands for _inversion_ of control; with this you undo the inversion. For your app, the container is just a bag of things and you can take things in and out whenever you feel like it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but doesn't the javax Provider do the same ?

Comment: Do what the same? Make the complete IoC container publicly available?

Comment: the "static access" I was talking about was a wrapper for `getBean()` for instantiating beans. the Provider does quite the same, or am I missing something ?

Comment: `Provider` is a dependency injected into your object which allows you to solve the lifecycle mismatch between the object it provides and your object. It is like a tailor-made factory object. That's quite unlike a global static method which returns the entire ApplicationContext.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85217/discussion-between-nati-and-marko-topolnik).