# Spring boot. How to take advantage of the Prototype scope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, runnable

I am trying to find a way to have a graceful Runnable bean creation in Spring boot. The point of the app is to have a service, which would take in some data, and start a monitored external process.

In my previous attempts I simply formed a regular `new MyRunnable()` and passed it to the execution service. Now I'm thinking how to properly do so using the Spring environment, and use the `@Scope("prototype")`.

I did find examples, which used `ApplicationContext.getBean(...)`, and a better approach of [Why is Spring's ApplicationContext.getBean considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad), but I still fail to properly digest how to actually call the `new MyRunnable()` in terms of one service, which would follow the simple idea of:

```
class MyService {
  public void triggerNewExternalTask() {
       ....
       executionService.run(new MyRunnable());
```

Comment: Unclear what problem you actually want to fix, but have you looked at the `@Scheduled` annotation in Spring (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a service, which would do something like a Jenkins would do - trigger multiple defined "cmd"s with attributes and monitor the outputs as separate "jobs". For this I am currently walking around the way of how to actually form the new Runnable implementation, and was thinking if I could achieve this with a Scope.PROTOTYPE and the Spring's Bean factory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're on the wrong path here.

Spring dependency injection is wonderful, but that does not mean that you'll *never* find a call to `new` in a properly written Spring Boot app.

This is a case where calling `new` is the right thing to do.  Every `Executor` in the pool should get its own instance of `Runnable`/`Callable` when it starts.

This is true for any method scoped variable: better to instantiate it in method scope and let the garbage collector clean it up when you exit the method.  No reason for Spring to be responsible for the bean life cycle in that case.

You go too far when you try to share `Runnable` instances, especially if they have state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The aim was a bit different - replace the "new MyRunnable()" call with something, that would be handled by Spring, but, in general, I understood your point. Will stick to the good old "new" then :)

Comment: I understood the aim. A new instance per Executor should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Even as the question is closed, stumbled over another solution, which is - @Lookup, which meets the task:
entity:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Proto {
    private static int counter;
    public Proto() {
        System.out.println("count: "+counter++);
    }
}
```

service:

```
@Service
public class ProtoService {
    @Lookup
    public Proto getProto() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
@Service
public class LookupWorks {
    @Autowired
    private ProtoService serv;

    @PostConstruct
    private void test() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        serv.getProto();
        serv.getProto();
        serv.getProto();
        serv.getProto();
        serv.getProto();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    }


}
```

with the output:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
count: 0
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3
count: 4
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```