# Spring - Explicit bean instantiation does not set @Value property

Tags: java, spring

I want to have a map of `@Component` instances of the same class. I init the instance like:

```
applicationContext.getBean(TorrentService.class)
```

TorrentService looks like this:

```
@Component
public class TorrentService {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private TorrentRepository repository;

    private BtClient client;

    @Value("${refreshInterval}")
    private int interval;

...
```

All `@Autowired` properties are initialized, except property `interval`.

When I initialize instance of `TorrentService` using `@Autowired` the property `interval` is set correctly. It's supposed to be set to `1000` instead it's set to `0`.

```
application.properties:

refreshInterval=1000
```

Is it because `applicationContext.getBean` is [outside IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad)?

What can be done?

Comment: can you show the output ? and what are you expecting ?

Comment: @Deadpool I edited the question. There's no error, only the property annotated with @ Value is not set.

Comment: show how you are initializing `TorrentService` and how you are checking for that value ?

Comment: I just @Autowire ApplicationContext and the call applicationContext.getBean(TorrentService.class). I check the value in debugger when a method of TorrentService is called.

Comment: That's not why, but I'm not sure why you're getting that. Always prefer constructor injection to field injection; that will help reduce the possibility for certain injection errors like this.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- could you provide an example of such an injection for this case?

Comment: Are you using Lombok?

Comment: yes, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Lombok isn't necessarily a problem (I use it all the time in Java); just checking. For constructor injection, make all your fields final and add a constructor `TorrentService(SimpMessagingTemplate template, TorrentRepository repository, @Value("${refreshInterval}") int interval)` with appropriate implementation. (Note that you can also use `Duration` with `@Value`, which might be more convenient than a plain `int` depending on how your implementation works.)

Comment: Could you please check if it works after you add `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` at your TorrentService class level?

Comment: Are you using Spring boot or not. If yes, can you provide where you have placed the application.properties file ?? it should be under /src/main/resources directory, if not, do you have already configured some class annotated with @PropertySource ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
@Value("#{refreshInterval}")
```