# Fixing BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException on Spring proxy cast on a non-singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring, casting, aop, proxy-classes

I'm having an issue with pulling a Spring bean from an application context.

When I try;

```
InnerThread instance = (InnerThread) SpringContextFactory.getApplicationContext().getBean("innerThread", InnerThread.class);
```

I get;

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'innerThread' must be of type [com.generic.InnerThread], but was actually of type [$Proxy26]
```

Without the specified class in the getBean() call I get a ClassCastException (which you can see in detail below).

The InnerThread bean is being initialized as a non-singleton, because I need multiple instances. The InnerThread class also extends Thread. The interesting thing is that this error shows up within OuterThread, which is set up in the exact same way the InnerThread is.

I've tried to include all relevant code listings/stack traces below. Could someone with more Spring experience tell me what is going on here?

---

### Code/Configuration Listing

*OuterThread.java snippet:*

```
public class OuterThread extends Thread {
    private Queue<InnerThread> createInnerThreads() {
        Queue<InnerThread> threads = new ArrayBlockingQueue();

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringContextFactory.getApplicationContext();
        int i = 0;
        for (SearchRule search : searches) {
            logger.debug("Number of times looped " + i++);
            //Seprated lines to get a better sense of what is going on
            Object proxy = ctx.getBean("innerThread", InnerThread.class);
            logger.debug(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(proxy));
            logger.debug("proxy.getClass(): " + proxy.getClass());
            logger.debug("proxy.getClass().getClassLoader(): " + proxy.getClass().getClassLoader());
            logger.debug("proxy.getClass().getDeclaringClass(): " + proxy.getClass().getDeclaringClass());
            logger.debug("InnerThread.class.getClassLoader(): " + InnerThread.class.getClassLoader());

            //---Exception here---
            InnerThread cst = (InnerThread) proxy;

            threads.add(cst);
        }
        return threads;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            OuterThread instance = (OuterThread) SpringContextFactory.getApplicationContext().getBean("outerThread", OuterThread.class);
            instance.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Fatal exception.", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

*SpringContextFactory.java:*

```
public class SpringContextFactory {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringContextFactory.class);
    private static ApplicationContext ctx;
    private static final String DEFAULT_PATH = "META-INF/app-context.xml";

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return getApplicationContext(DEFAULT_PATH);
    }

    public static synchronized ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(String path) {
        if (ctx == null) return createApplicationContext(path);
        else return ctx;
    }

    private static ApplicationContext createApplicationContext(String path) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Loading Spring Context...");
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(path);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Spring Context Loaded");
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

*app-context.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- persistence context from separate jar -->
    <import resource="persistence-context.xml"/>

    <bean id="outerThread" class="com.generic.OuterThread" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean id="innerThread" class="com.generic.InnerThread" scope="prototype"/>

</beans>
```

### Stack Trace

```
2009-05-08 14:34:37,341 [main] DEBUG com.generic.OuterThread.init(OuterThread.java:59) - Initializing OuterThread object, com.generic.OuterThread@1c8fb4b[em=org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@e2892b,currentTime=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1241634874841,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2009,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=19,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_YEAR=126,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=34,SECOND=34,MILLISECOND=841,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000],maxConcurrentThreads=5,reconId=3,reportUsername=TEST,useOffset=false,username=removed,uuid=bf61494d-ff96-431c-a41f-1e292d0c9fbe,name={T,h,r,e,a,d,-,1},priority=5,threadQ=<null>,eetop=0,single_step=false,daemon=false,stillborn=false,target=<null>,group=java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10],contextClassLoader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7,inheritedAccessControlContext=java.security.AccessControlContext@1524d43,threadLocals=<null>,inheritableThreadLocals=java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap@2cbc86,stackSize=0,nativeParkEventPointer=0,tid=9,threadStatus=0,parkBlocker=<null>,blocker=<null>,blockerLock=java.lang.Object@a68fd8,stopBeforeStart=false,throwableFromStop=<null>,uncaughtExceptionHandler=<null>]
2009-05-08 14:34:37,341 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:385) - No local transaction to join
2009-05-08 14:34:37,529 [main] DEBUG com.generic.OuterThread.createInnerThreads(OuterThread.java:139) - Number of times looped 0
2009-05-08 14:34:37,529 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) - Creating instance of bean 'searchThread' with merged definition [Root bean: class [com.generic.InnerThread]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireCandidate=true; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/app-context.xml]]
2009-05-08 14:34:37,545 [main] DEBUG com.generic.InnerThread.<init>(InnerThread.java:50) - Constructing InnerThread object, com.generic.InnerThread@1080876[em=<null>,coolScheme=<null>,coolUrl=<null>,date=<null>,error=<null>,millisecondsTaken=0,thresholdMet=false,reconId=0,result=-2,searchId=0,username=<null>,uuid=<null>,name={T,h,r,e,a,d,-,2},priority=5,threadQ=<null>,eetop=0,single_step=false,daemon=false,stillborn=false,target=<null>,group=java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10],contextClassLoader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7,inheritedAccessControlContext=java.security.AccessControlContext@1524d43,threadLocals=<null>,inheritableThreadLocals=java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap@3aef16,stackSize=0,nativeParkEventPointer=0,tid=10,threadStatus=0,parkBlocker=<null>,blocker=<null>,blockerLock=java.lang.Object@126c6ea,stopBeforeStart=false,throwableFromStop=<null>,uncaughtExceptionHandler=<null>]
2009-05-08 14:34:37,545 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:203) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2009-05-08 14:34:37,545 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:203) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2009-05-08 14:34:37,560 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:108) - Adding transactional method [report] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
2009-05-08 14:34:37,560 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.buildAdvisors(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:494) - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'searchThread' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
2009-05-08 14:34:37,560 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:113) - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.generic.InnerThread@1080876]
2009-05-08 14:34:37,591 [main] DEBUG com.generic.OuterThread.createInnerThreads(OuterThread.java:141) - $Proxy26@1594a88[h=org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy@1f0cf51]
2009-05-08 14:34:37,591 [main] DEBUG com.generic.OuterThread.createInnerThreads(OuterThread.java:142) - proxy.getClass(): class $Proxy26
2009-05-08 14:34:37,591 [main] DEBUG com.generic.OuterThread.createInnerThreads(OuterThread.java:143) - proxy.getClass().getClassLoader(): sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
2009-05-08 14:34:37,591 [main] DEBUG com.generic.OuterThread.createInnerThreads(OuterThread.java:144) - proxy.getClass().getDeclaringClass(): null
2009-05-08 14:34:37,591 [main] DEBUG com.generic.OuterThread.createInnerThreads(OuterThread.java:145) - InnerThread.class.getClassLoader(): sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
2009-05-08 14:34:37,591 [main] ERROR com.generic.OuterThread.run(OuterThread.java:101) - Exception in OuterThread, ending reconciliation.
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy26 cannot be cast to com.generic.InnerThread
    at com.generic.OuterThread.createInnerThreads(OuterThread.java:148)
    at com.generic.OuterThread.run(OuterThread.java:65)
    at com.generic.OuterThread.main(OuterThread.java:170)
```

---

### Similar questions that do not answer my question

- [Auto-cast Spring Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812178/auto-cast-spring-beans)
- [ClassCastException when casting to  the same class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Once again, after spending hours trying to debug this I find the answer right after posting on StackOverflow.

A key point that I left out from my question is that InnerThread has a transactional method (sorry thought this was irrelevant). This is the important difference between OuterThread and InnerThread.

From the [Spring documentation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/index.html):

> Note
>
> Multiple  sections are collapsed into a single unified auto-proxy creator at runtime, which applies the strongest proxy settings that any of the  sections (typically from different XML bean definition files) specified. This also applies to the  and  elements.
>
> To be clear: **using 'proxy-target-class="true"'** on ,  or  elements will force the use of [CGLIB proxies](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types) for all three of them.

Adding the above to my configuration (based in persistance-context.xml, which you can see loaded above)  line seems to fix the problem. However, I think this may be a quick fix workaround as opposed to real solution.

I think I've got a few deeper issues here, number one being that I find Spring as confusing as expletive deleted. Second I should probably be using [Spring's TaskExecutor](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor) to kick off my threads. Third my threads should implement Runnable instead of extending Thread (See SO question below).

**See Also**

- [BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException using
  ServiceLocatorFactoryBean and
  @Transactional](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=66083) 
  (Nothing better then finding a thread off Google after hours of searching to have a response that says "This has already been answered a million times.")
- [Section 6.6 in    the Spring
  Docs.](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-proxying)
- [Java: “implements Runnable” vs. “extends Thread”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Comment: Check tom's answer (first class should be interface though, fixed that but waiting for peer review). I think it's the right direction to solve this in a proper way. Please re-think the "correct answer" since it might make people add additional dependencies and configurations that they don't really need(/want).

Answer (score 45):

Annotate your `@Configuration` class with

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

You also have to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This should really be marked as the "Accepted Answer".

Comment: Really, it needs not to use CGLIB proxies for correct type matching.

Comment: This worked really well for me. It should be accepted answer.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Should be marked as "Accepted Answer".

Comment: It works. But I agree with antonu17. It's overkill. Solving this is a lot more simple. The issue lies in the direction of the answer of tom

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this issue is by extending the runnable interface and creating your own:

```
public interface MyInterface extends Runnable {
  // your own method declarations here
  void doSomething();
  ...
}
```

Then you should implement your interface instead of the runnable:

```
@Component("myInterface")
@Scope("prototype")
     public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {

          // your own method declarations here
          public void doSomething(){
          ...
          }


          // implement run from Runnable Interface
          @Transactional
          public void run(){
                .....
          }

             ...
        }
```

This will work fine:

```
...
    MyInterface mynterface = SpringApplicationContext.getBean("myInterface", MyInterface.class);

    myInterface.doSomething();
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(myInterface);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but try making an interface InnerThreadInterface, then let InnerThread class extend it.

After that you should be able to do:

InnerThreadInterface inner = ctx.getBean("innerThread", InnerThread.class);

Comment: I gave this a try, unfortunately no dice on this one.

Comment: This one actually helped in my case, but the example is slightly wrong. It should be: `InnerThreadInterface inner = ctx.getBean("innerThread", InnerThreadInterface.class);`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue even though I referenced CGLIB and used the proxy-target-class="true" setting. I determined ehcache:annotation tag was to blame... Removing the following configuration solved this for me. Fortunately, I was able to use hibernate level 2 caching instead of having to use ehcache declarative caching.

```
<ehcache:annotations>
    <ehcache:caching id="myCacheModel" cacheName="myCache"/>
    <ehcache:flushing id="myFlushModel" cacheNames="myCache" when="after"/>
</ehcache:annotations>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this problem would be to implement an interface and request the interface from spring, the proxy would fully implement the interface, and the cast shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Not always a practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

> This is just a guess, but try making
>   an interface InnerThreadInterface,
>   then let InnerThread class extend it.
>        After that you should be able to do:

I use this way instead of what is posted above and it worked fine. There was no need of setting the proxy-target-class to true, this required more libraries that wasn't on my classpath.

```
InnerThreadInterface inner = (InnerThreadInterface)ctx.getBean("innerThread");
```

Answer (score -1):

create a DAO interface and implement the DAO interface to the SERVICE class and provide the config details of SERVICE class in the applicationContext.xml file i.e., the spring config file and access the bean using the bean id and reference the instance of the so instantiated proxy object to the DAO interface ... it will work perfectly fine ....

Answer (score -2):

There was this problem until I just restart Idea and rebuilt the Maven project.