# how do i get @Service bean by its default qualifier bean name in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have many ServiceImpl beans but I want to access specific bean by its default name like

```
 class SuperServiceImpl {}

 class UserServiceImpl extends SuperServiceImpl {}

 class PlaceServiceImpl extends SuperServiceImpl {}

 public SuperServiceImpl getServiceImpl(String qualifierName) {
       // if qualifierName="userServiceImpl"
       //   return UserServiceImpl
 }
```

I tried to implement following solution

[Auto-cast Spring Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812178/auto-cast-spring-beans)

but I'm not getting `getBean()` method on `ApplicationContext` reference.

Comment: Can't you use `@Autowire @Qualifier("beanname")` over a field/setter?

Comment: How are you using `applicationContext.getBean(qualifier)`? Also, how are you creating the beans of type `SuperServiceImpl`?

Comment: @sp00m I don't want to autowire all my ServiceImpl on class loading. instead I want to load specific Service on demand.And I read somewhere its possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found easiest solution..

1)I autowired ApplicationContext

2)Passed default qualifier name to method getBean(defaultQualifierName)

thats it..

thanks guys for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

`return applicationContext.getBean(qualifierName, SuperServiceImpl.class)` you may want to define an interface for `SuperServiceImpl` and use `return applicationContext.getBean(qualifierName, SuperService.class)` instead, especially if you have multiple implementations.

Of course, to make that work you need to define your beans properly:

- With XML the qualifier is the `id` attribute of the `bean` element
- With Javaconfig, the name of the method is the bean name by default. You can override that of course with the `name` attribute of the `@Bean` annotation